# Placeholder in MessageDialog does not work C#

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am trying to use a placeholder in the string, but it does not work. Is it just that MessageDialog does not support placeholders? When the user loses the game, MessageDialog shows up and i want to display to user the right answer.
Here are some pictures to describe the problem.

[image]
[image]

Thanks for all!

Comment: Don't post screenshots of source code. Paste in the text. Then it's searchable. Also, when a method doesn't do what you hoped it would, just read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your trying to do: string.format. But you forgot to do the format. Personally I'd use: the $ IE `$"You lose! The answer was : {DisplayWord.Current}"`

Comment: If I may suggest some additional information, you could add that the reason the OPs code works is because he is calling the [following method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/windows/apps/br208688), i.e. a a method that takes content and **title**. Also, Format is with a big F. and "You're"

Comment: When i put the DisplayWord.Current into curly brackets there, it displays me : You lose! The answer was : {DisplayWord.Current}, instead of answer.

Comment: Can I revert back to a comment..... @M.Kesküll - did you preface the string with the "$" , also what version of .NET?  If it's an older .NET you use string.format.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Trey!